# how to check whether a inputted value is a character or not

Tags: c

so we are working on a mastermind game and whenever someone inputs a string, it freaks.

```
    //INVALIDS
if (space1!='a' && space1!='b' && space1!='c' && space1!='d' && space1!='e' && space1!='f')
    {
    printf("Invalid entry.\n");
    goto label;
    }
if (space2!='a' && space2!='b' && space2!='c' && space2!='d' && space2!='e' && space2!='f')
    {
    printf("Invalid entry.\n");
    goto label;
    }
if (space3!='a' && space3!='b' && space3!='c' && space3!='d' && space3!='e' && space3!='f')
    {
    printf("Invalid entry.\n");
    goto label;
    }
if (space4!='a' && space4!='b' && space4!='c' && space4!='d' && space4!='e' && space4!='f')
    {
    printf("Invalid entry.\n");
    goto label;
    }
```

Comment: This is really bad code.

Comment: To clarify on iharob's comment, the code is excessively repetitive and the goto is highly unnecessary.

Comment: Just some tips to make the code cleaner:
You should do the checks on an array rather than individual variables. Define a char array called space of a sufficient size and then you can access specific characters like `space[0]  != 'a'` . Additionally you can check whether a character is within the `'a' <= space[i] <= 'f'` range instead of checking all of them, this should work on sane locales.

Comment: Honestly, I'm freaking a bit just looking at that code...

Comment: What exactly does "it freaks" mean?  What's the error message you get?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Alexguitar Checking alphabetic character  using a range like that is not guaranteed to work in C. It is only guaranteed that the characters '0' through '9' are consecutive - there is no guarantee the other letters are consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the input in an `char` array and then process it for single character. If there are more than one alphaneumeric characters then show error or do whatever you want.

Note: This is not the way you should write code and avoid `goto` it generates some really-annoying-bugs.

### Some snippet

```
char s[100];
do
{
scanf("%s",s);
...
}while(strlen(s)>1..)
process s[100]
```

As mentioned by **iharob** a better way to use it is to `%n` specifier. The %n format specifier,when used in a scanf() is expected to store the count of the number of characters of the format string already processed by the function into an argument of type int*.
  So you can have

```
 int len;
 scanf("%s%n",s,&len);
 //process len
```

**chux** mentioned a better solution: use `fgets()`.
For example..

```
fgets(s,len+1,stdin);
//process s[]
```

Comment: @iharob.: Can I modify the post? Yes! the answer can be improved but it works

Comment: @iharob.: Please check my answer.

Comment: `scanf("%s%n",s,&len);` is also a problem.  `len` will have the number of `char` processed, but what good it that?  It is not necessarily the `strlen(s)`.  Consider `"\n 123"`.  `len` with have a value of 5 (previous line's enter, space, 1,2,3).   Suggest `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux.:please check my answer..I have modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the validation logic into its own function.  You can take advantage of the `strchr` function in the standard library for this particular test:

```
int isValid( int c ) 
{
  static const char *validChars = "abcdef";
  return strchr( c, validChars ) != NULL;
}
```

If the value of `c` is one of the characters in `validChars`, `strchr` will return a pointer to that character, otherwise it will return NULL.  So if `c` is not one of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, or `f`, the `isValid` function will return 0 (false), otherwise it will return 1 (true).

Now, I am assuming that your `spaceN` variables are all separate inputs, not part of the same input.  Probably the simplest (if not most intuitive) approach to guarantee a single-character input is the following:

```
char c;
if ( scanf( " %c%*[^\n]", &c ) == 1 ) // note leading blank in format string!
  // valid single-character input
```

This will tell `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace (including newlines), read and store the first non-whitespace character to `c`, and then consume *but not store* everything up to the next newline.

*NOTE* - anytime you find yourself creating a bunch of variables of the same type with the same name and an ordinal like `space1`, `space2`, `space3`, `space4`, then you're usually better off using an array.

Putting this all together, we get:

```
int space[4]; 

/**
 * Get the number of elements in the space array; this way we
 * don't have to hardcode a size in our loop
 */
size_t numElements = sizeof space / sizeof space[0];

for ( i = 0; i < numElements; i++ )
{
  int done = 0;
  do
  {
    printf( "Gimme an input (0 to quit): " );
    fflush( stdout );
    if ( scanf( " %c%*[^\n]", &space[i] ) != 1 )
    {
      fprintf( stderr, "Error reading input, bailing...\n" );
      exit( 0 );
    }
    done = isValid( space[i] );
    if ( !done && space[i] != '0' )
      fprintf( stderr, "Invalid input, try again\n" );
  } while ( !done && space[i] != '0' );

  if ( space[i] == '0' )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Got a '0' for input, quitting...\n" );
    exit( 0 );
  }
}
```

Without seeing more of your code, I don't know if this is useful or not.